# Node.js 10-20 sec loading time when restarting

Tags: node.js, express, loading, startup, nodemon

I am running node.js with nodemon and express js. Whenever I make some random changes it takes forever to load the page after a restart (then after 20-30 sec it's normal loading). The problem is frustrating because I need to wait 20-30sec for each changes. Obviously, I would like to visualize what I've done much faster.

This problem is random because if I load a page in chrome and load the same page in firefox, it's the chrome who gets the slow loading time. It's like, "the first one who is connecting to the server gets the slow loading time". This is not specific a browser problem because I have tested loading the page from two different devices at the same time and the same problem hits the first one who loads the page.

I know that the problem is not the node.js itself because the command line prints out the result. The problem occur when I visualize a random result though a browser.

I am running my node js on windows 8.1

//Jacob

Comment: Post code and logs. Logs of HTTP requets from both the server and from the browser, possibly.

Comment: I have the same issue - did you ever find a resolution?  curl works fine, but chrome will not load the page for 10-20s after a node restart of the express service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js server very slow starting time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408513/node-js-server-very-slow-starting-time)