# Running Webpack-dev-server in docker is significantly slower than on local machine

Tags: macos, docker, webpack

I'm moving most of my development processes into docker to ensure a parallel development environment between computers so there are no odd bugs or issues due to version mis-match, etc.

All of this is going great, except that when running webpack-dev-server inside of docker, the build process is substantially slower than when I run it just locally on my computer. (Like 3-5 minutes in docker vs 30 seconds to 1 min locally). Is there any way to speed this up? Is it just an issue with docker/webpack interacting with a lot of files on my hard drive through a mounted volume?

If it matters, my host system is a Mac running High Sierra on an i7 with 16bg of ram.

I'm running docker for mac, docker -v returns: Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

I hope all of this is clear enough, let me know if I can add any information!

Comment: Which version of docker?

Comment: I updated my question, but I'm using docker for mac, docker -v returns: Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Comment: Are you mounting your local dev directory into the container?

Comment: If you are it's likely this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494110/1318694

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing! I swapped to cached mode and my build went from 3+ minutes down to 30-40 seconds. Still slower than locally, but much more manageable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For those in a similar spot, as Matt suggested, the issues were coming from having a mounted volume. I sped the build up significantly by using docker's volume cache mode. [The docs on it are here.](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#performance-implications-of-host-container-file-system-consistency)

The command looks something like this:

`docker run -v \local\director:docker\directory:cached dockerImage`

Comment: Thank you! Spent so long on figuring this out and this answer was the key, it reduced my build time from 30s to <1s. For anyone using a docker-compose.yml file, you can use the same syntax and add `:cached` to the end of your volume.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using `delegated` instead of `cached` as per the documentation:

> **Cached**: The host is authoritative in this case. There may be delays
>   before writes on a host are available to the container.
>
> **Delegated**: The container is authoritative. There may be delays until
>   updates within the container appear on the host.

So the docker-compose file would be as following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  front:
    container_name: my-front-dev
    image: my-front-dev-image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: front/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 5002:80
    volumes:
      - ./front/:/app/:rw:delegated
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from adding **cached** volume flag to your docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  front:
    container_name: my-front-dev
    image: my-front-dev-image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: front/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 5002:80
    volumes:
      - ./front/:/app/:rw,cached
```

I also recommend you to **upgrade docker-for-mac to newest version** (bump to version 2.0.0 had significant performance improvement on my mac).

Last recommendation is to **raise default CPU/Memory limits** in docker-for-mac settings:

[image: docker cpu/memory limits]

Comment: You have this in your volume `./front/:/app/:rw,cached`. What does the last part `:rw` do?

Answer (score 1):

## Windows

A lot of these answers apply mostly to Mac users. If you're on **Windows** you should run your Docker commands in your Linux distro. It was a night and day difference for me. No messing with caching or anything. If you already have Docker Desktop installed you just have to make sure you already have a Linux distro installed. It's easy to setup if you don't.

Basically, any read/write process between Windows and Linux takes a long time. If you run your Docker container inside Windows Subsystem for Linux the file read/write is near instantaneous because the file are going from Linux to Linux. You will have to move your files from whatever directory in Windows to a directory in your Linux distro, but that shouldn't be a problem assuming you're using git.

Resources:

[Article that kind of explains it](https://www.createit.com/blog/make-docker-on-windows-fast-again-2022/)

[Docker documentation on setting up WSL 2 and a Linux Distro](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/)

[VSCode working with WSL 2](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/09/03/wsl2)